# SNORT: Is a PCRE on SSNs intensive

Tags: linux, snort, ips

I'm trying to write a Snort rule to look for SSNs.  Due to the limitations of the appliance in place I can not use the pre-processor settings.  How intense would it be to run a PCRE rule for SSNs?  This would essentially perform a regex comparison on every packet which seems pretty intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement DLP using Snort? You might find [these](https://code.google.com/p/snortdlp/) [links](http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/detection/host-based-detection-data-loss-prevention-open-source-tools-34055) interesting.

Any kind of regex processing is bound to be intensive if there is a lot of network traffic. You can perhaps make your rule filters more specific so that Snort does not attempt to do regex match against everything? Target applications/protocols that are likely to contain interesting data.